# Feature test actingas effects all guards?

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I have two different user objects in my application, one `App\User` and one `App\Admin`. For both, I have different guards for authentication.

My default guard is the `web` guard for model `App\User` and I also have an `admin` guard for the model `App\Admin`.

For example, this code

```
  $admin = factory(\App\Admin::class)->make();
  \Auth::guard('admin')->login($admin);

  dd([\Auth::check(), \Auth::guard('admin')->check()]);
```

returns

> [false, true]

as expected.

However, inside my feature test I am doing this:

```
$admin = factory(\App\Admin::class)->make();
$response = $this->actingAs($admin, 'admin')
                 ->get('/admin');
dd([\Auth::check(), \Auth::guard('admin')->check()]);
```

this returns for some reason

> [true, true]

This causes all kind of errors (For example I have  a log middleware for normal users, and trying to store the admin as normal user throws foreign_key exceptions etc.).

Why is `actingAs` enabling both guards? Is it a bug in Laravel 5.6 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I have the same issue, no matter what guard I specify.

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid yes I solved it as explained in the checked answer. Does this not work for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `actingAs` method, Laravel changes the default guard to `admin` internally (In this case).

Please use the code below

```php
$defaultGuard = config('auth.defaults.guard');

$admin = factory(\App\Admin::class)->make();
$this->actingAs($admin, 'admin');
\Auth::shouldUse($defaultGuard);

$response = $this->get('/admin');

dd([\Auth::check(), \Auth::guard('admin')->check()]);
```

Also you can extract a method `actingAsAdmin` in the `TestCase` class, so that you can reuse the function.

```php
public function actingAsAdmin($admin) {
    $defaultGuard = config('auth.defaults.guard');
    $this->actingAs($admin, 'admin');
    \Auth::shouldUse($defaultGuard);

    return $this;
}
```

And call this function like below.

```php
$admin = factory(\App\Admin::class)->make();
$response = $this->actingAsAdmin($admin)->get('/admin');
dd([\Auth::check(), \Auth::guard('admin')->check()]);
```

Comment: The second solution seems nice, but `\Auth::shouldUse` does not change the default guard outside the function. If you output `config('auth.defaults.guard')` after you called `actingAsAdmin` then it will be the-non default guard.

Comment: I noticed it because when creating two `get` responses both using `actingAsAdmin`

Answer (score 0):

I was calling `actingAs()` in my setup method, but needed to use a different guard for one of my tests. All I needed to do in the test was:

```php
Auth::logout();
$this->actingAs($admin, "admin");
```

The key was specifying the guard in the function call, it wouldn't work otherwise.